# Disable horizontal scroll on screen edge in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a Drawer that slides from Left side, but when using FlatList and my content is full width and height, i can't then swipe on left screen edge to bring drawer because it just slides the screens.

My current workaround not ideal is to have View component placed outside FlatList.

```
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          height: '100%',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: 15,
          zIndex: 1,
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={_slides}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
        bounces={false}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToAlignment="center"
      />
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}` in FlatList component and try again

Fullcode

```
 <View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          height: '100%',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: 15,
          zIndex: 1,
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={_slides}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
        bounces={false}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToAlignment="center"
        contentContainerStyle={{ marginRight: 10, marginLeft: 10 }}
      />
    </View>
```

This will create an invisible padding on both sides of the FlatList, allowing you to swipe on the screen edge without triggering the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Not 100% sure it does create it, but only on left side. but if i have different colors for each screen then the padding will show the previous color. Might have to play around with this, thank you

Comment: Then Try updated code, but i'm not confident if that works but you can manage it.